# Dont ReRun After Faild one Test Case

Tags: selenium, testing, automated-tests, ui-automation, selenide

after field one testcase, successful test Case skiped why ? how can i  fix it?

```
public class RadioButtonTests  {
@BeforeSuite()
    public void ConfigTests(){
    open("https://demoqa.com/radio-button");
}
@Test
public void RadioButtonYes(){//successful
  $(withText("Yes")).click();
    Assert.assertTrue($(byId("yesRadio")).isDisplayed());
}

@Test
public void RadioButtonNo(){//field
    Assert.assertTrue($(byId("noRadio")).isEnabled());
}

@Test
public void Ra(){//field
    $(withText("Yes")).shouldNot(Condition.visible);

}
@Test
public void Radio(){//successful
    $(withText("Yes")).shouldBe(Condition.visible);
    Assert.assertTrue($(byId("yesRadio")).isSelected());
}
```

}
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBNYt.png)

Comment: The question is unclear. Please put the question more clearly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.